# django custom save insert to multiple table

Tags: django, django-models

I have an Item table and TransactionLog table, When I create an item it should also create a log

this is my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
itemid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
managed = False
db_table = 'items'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    TransactionLog.objects.create(itemid=self.cl_itemid,
    trans_desc="Add Clearance Item",
    trans_recorded=timezone.now())
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TransactionLog(models.Model):
log_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
itemid = models.ForeignKey('Item', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='itemid', blank=True, null=True)
trans_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
trans_recorded = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'transaction_log'
```

but When I try to insert it's saying ***Cannot assign "'CL-20221106-0000'": "TransactionLog.itemid" must be a "Item" instance.*** maybe because the Item isnt created yet?

Comment: Can't use the Signals?

Comment: I haven't thought about that sorry still learning

Comment: uhm do you have a example?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is Use Signal insted of savind data on `save` method.

```
#signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from yourapp.models import Item, TransactionLog

@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def create_transaction_log(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       TransactionLog.objects.create(itemid=instance.cl_itemid,
          trans_desc="Add Clearance Item",trans_recorded=timezone.now())
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAPPConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourappname'

   def ready(self):
      import yourapp.signals
```

Comment: still the same error Cannot assign "'CL-20221106-0000'": "TransactionLog.itemid" must be a "Item" instance

Comment: it's saving but only in Item table not in TransactionLog

Comment: it's working but idk this looks redudant? TransactionLog.objects.create(cl_itemid=ClearanceItem.objects.get(cl_itemid=instance.cl_itemid)

Comment: try with `instance` its a fk right. else. 
`t = TransactionLog.objects.create()
  t. cl_itemid = instance 
  t.save()
`